# Creating multiple buttons in java scene

Tags: java, eclipse, button, javafx

I am attempting to create a scene with multiple buttons and I am having some issues.

What I have now is this:

```
public class Tester extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
Button btn1 = new Button();
btn1.setText("Start Game");
Button btn2 = new Button();
btn2.setText("Exit");
btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()); 
btn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Game Start");
    }
});

Pane root = new Pane();
btn1.setLayoutX(500);
btn1.setLayoutY(530);
root.getChildren().add(btn1);
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
primaryStage.show();
```

I am trying to figure out what I need to do to have a second button.  At the moment, I cant seem to have a second event handler.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the second button being shown but not clickable? or not shown at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update to your program to:

1. Define an action (display "Wumpus Hunt Complete!") for the second button.
2. Add the second button to the scene so that it can be seen.

The event handler for taking action for a button is an example of an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Sample Code:

```
Button btn1 = new Button();
btn1.setText("Start Game");
Button btn2 = new Button();
btn2.setText("Exit");
btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Wumpus Hunt Complete!");
    }
});
btn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Game Start");
    }
});

Pane root = new Pane();
btn1.setLayoutX(500);
btn1.setLayoutY(530);
root.getChildren().add(btn1);
btn2.setLayoutX(500);
btn2.setLayoutY(630);
root.getChildren().add(btn2);
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
primaryStage.show();
```